# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT with SUM() and multiple JOINs inside subquery

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I'm very average with MySQL, but usually I can write all the needed queries after reading documentation and searching for examples. Now, I'm in the situation where I spent 3 days re-searching and re-writing queries, but I can't get it to work the exact way I need. Here's the deal:

1st table (**mpt_companies**) contains companies:

```
| company_id | company_title |
------------------------------
| 1          | Company A     |
| 2          | Company B     |
```

2nd table (**mpt_payment_methods**) contains payment methods:

```
| payment_method_id | payment_method_title |
--------------------------------------------
| 1                 | Cash                 |
| 2                 | PayPal               |
| 3                 | Wire                 |
```

3rd table (**mpt_payments**) contains payments for each company:

```
| payment_id | company_id | payment_method_id | payment_amount |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 1          | 1                 | 10.00          |
| 2          | 2          | 3                 | 15.00          |
| 3          | 1          | 1                 | 20.00          |
| 4          | 1          | 2                 | 10.00          |
```

I need to list each company along with many stats. One of stats is the sum of payments in each payment method. In other words, the **result should be**:

```
| company_id | company_title | payment_data            |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | Company A     | Cash:30.00,PayPal:10.00 |
| 2          | Company B     | Wire:15.00              |
```

Obviously, I need to:

- Select all the companies;
- Join payments for each company;
- Join payment methods for each payment;
- Calculate sum of payments in each method;
- GROUP_CONCAT payment methods and sums;

Unfortunately, SUM() doesn't work with GROUP_CONCAT. Some solutions I found on this site suggest using CONCAT, but that doesn't produce the list I need. Other solutions suggest using CAST(), but maybe I do something wrong because it doesn't work too. This is the closest query I wrote, which returns each company, and unique list of payment methods used by each company, but doesn't return the sum of payments:

```
SELECT *,
(some other sub-queries I need...),
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(mpt_payment_methods.payment_method_title))
FROM mpt_payments
JOIN mpt_payment_methods
ON mpt_payments.payment_method_id=mpt_payment_methods.payment_method_id
WHERE mpt_payments.company_id=mpt_companies.company_id
ORDER BY mpt_payment_methods.payment_method_title) AS payment_data
FROM mpt_companies
```

Then I tried:

```
SELECT *,
(some other sub-queries I need...),
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(mpt_payment_methods.payment_method_title), ':',  CAST(SUM(mpt_payments.payment_amount) AS CHAR))
FROM mpt_payments
JOIN mpt_payment_methods
ON mpt_payments.payment_method_id=mpt_payment_methods.payment_method_id
WHERE mpt_payments.company_id=mpt_companies.company_id
ORDER BY mpt_payment_methods.payment_method_title) AS payment_data
FROM mpt_companies
```

...and many other variations, but all of them either returned query errors, either didn't return/format data I need.

The closest answer I could find was [MySQL one to many relationship: GROUP_CONCAT or JOIN or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034494/mysql-one-to-many-relationship-group-concat-or-join-or-both) but after spending 2 hours re-writing the provided query to work with my data, I couldn't do it.

Could anyone give me a suggestion, please?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: Yes, I will use PHP to process "payment_data" field to format it the way I need, but I strongly believe that calculating sums and grouping payments with MySQL query is a much more effective solution instead of using PHP loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by aggregating twice. First for the sum of payments per method and company and then to concatenate the sums for each company.

```
SELECT x.company_id,
       x.company_title,
       group_concat(payment_amount_and_method) payment_data
       FROM (SELECT c.company_id,
                    c.company_title,
                    concat(pm.payment_method_title, ':', sum(p.payment_amount)) payment_amount_and_method
                    FROM mpt_companies c
                         INNER JOIN mpt_payments p
                                    ON p.company_id = c.company_id
                         INNER JOIN mpt_payment_methods pm
                                    ON pm.payment_method_id = p.payment_method_id
                    GROUP BY c.company_id,
                             c.company_title,
                             pm.payment_method_id,
                             pm.payment_method_title) x
      GROUP BY x.company_id,
               x.company_title;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e9b62c552c71938a0a6fac23e7ab6f70)

Comment: Wow, that was very fast and very complex (for me) :) I tried aggregating twice myself, but failed. I see your example works perfectly for my needs, so I'm going to study it now to understand how the query works instead of blindly copying it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
SELECT company_id, 
    company_title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(payment_method_title, ':', payment_amount)
    ) AS payment_data
FROM (
    SELECT c.company_id, c.company_title, pm.payment_method_id, pm.payment_method_title, SUM(p.payment_amount) AS payment_amount
    FROM mpt_payments p
    JOIN mpt_companies c ON p.company_id = c.company_id
    JOIN mpt_payment_methods pm ON pm.payment_method_id = p.payment_method_id
    GROUP BY p.company_id, p.payment_method_id
) distinct_company_payments
GROUP BY distinct_company_payments.company_id
;
```

Comment: Thanks. Your query looks less complex to me, but I couldn't get it to work because of this error - #1558 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20.

Comment: Seems like an error with the database rather than the query?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177465/column-count-of-mysql-proc-is-wrong-expected-20-found-16-the-table-is-probabl . Runs ok for me!  Maybe restart your mysql server?

Comment: My query isn't really any less complex unfortunately.  `INNER JOIN` is exactly the same as `JOIN`.  My GROUP BY is doing the minimum columns, but it wouldn't work if mysql's ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode was turned on.

Comment: Ran mysql_upgrade, and that error went away. Now I only see "#1630 - FUNCTION mpt.GROUP_CONCAT does not exist". The same error is also displayed if I run the query in fiddle provided by sticky bit - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e9b62c552c71938a0a6fac23e7ab6f70

Comment: Sorry, a couple of small issues with that - should be all working now :)

Comment: Yes, works fine now. Thank you, going to study this query too.